# Jest & Firebase Emulator - wait for trigger function to be called

Tags: firebase, jestjs, firebase-tools

My `package.json` file contains the following:

```json
...
    "jest": "jest --runInBand",
    "test": "firebase emulators:exec 'npm run jest'"
...
```

which allows me to run tests based on `jest` with a running Firebase Emulator.

Consider the following piece of code:

```js
describe("MyTests", () => {
  const req = supertest(app);
  let user: admin.auth.UserRecord;
  let idToken: string | undefined;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const email = "test@gmail.com";
    const password = "password";
    user = await admin.auth().createUser({ email: email, password: password });

    await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    idToken = await auth.currentUser?.getIdToken();
  });

// actual tests
```

Where I'm creating a Firebase user, which in turn trigger a function (`functions.auth.user().onCreate(foo)`).

I do notice that this `foo` function is being executed **after** the jest test suite is running:

```
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.841 s, estimated 16 s
Ran all test suites.
✔  Script exited successfully (code 0)
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-foo"
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
i  functions: Stopping Functions Emulator
i  functions: Waiting for all functions to finish...
i  functions: Finished "us-central1-foo" in ~1s
```

How can I wait for it to be executed from inside the `beforeAll()` function?

Comment: how you found any solution?

Comment: @Piotr no, still waiting for help

Comment: My „solution” is wait for 2.5 seconds 

Answer (score 1):

**I found a pretty hacky solution to make this work, but it works.**

When i was researching this question my self i realized that the logs from the Emulator UI is available on a websocket on `ws://localhost:4500`

So what i did was that i created a function that checks when functions start and when functions finishes bases on the firebase loggs `Beginning execution of "` and `Finished "`

I also created a function that adds a listener that gets triggered when no functions has been triggered within 100ms from the last `Finished "`-message

The Emulator UI is not included by default in the `firebase emulators:exec`-command so you need to run it with `firebase emulators:exec --ui "npm test"` for the logs service to start.

I use it like this

```
beforeAll(async () => {
  await initFirebaseListener()
})
afterAll(() => {
  closeSocket()
})

describe('wait for firebase', () => {
  test('should wait for firebase', async () => {
    // do stuff that triggers some auth, firestore, RTDB or whatever function
    await waitForFirebaseToFinish()
    // Get something that i can validate
    // expect(theThingIWasWaitingFor).toEqual('the expected value that the trigged did')
  })
})
```

**Key takeaways:**

- You need to close the socket for the process to terminate after test execution
- This is super hacky, can break in the next update of firebase-admin
- You need to add `--ui` to the `emulators:exec` command for the logs service to start.
- It works, for me at least.

Created a gist with the code, link down below.
I used the websocket npm library (`npm install -D websocket`) for subscribing to the logs, but you could use another library if you like.

https://gist.github.com/Gurey/8301022f8357b3a7d74cefca4b598646